# Join Active Directory on a DC VM in azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, domaincontroller

I'd like to set up a small lab in Azure.
Two vm's, one is the domain controller and the other is the Windows 10 client.
Both are in the same subnet IP 10.0.0.1 /24.
My problem is , my client can't join the ad on my dc. And the client get always "AD with name ifa.local can't contacted".
I've some picture from the window, ip config and dns suffix I added.

Has anyone an idea why it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure Windows 10 VM can reach the DC.  Just because there in the same subnet doesn't mean that, you need to update the DNS server on the 'Azure Network interface' for the Windows 10 machine or on the VNet to point to the DC IP.

That will allow you to join the domain.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3nD7.png)

[image: Example]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I updated this on azure but I still facing the same issue. Do I have to open some port on the azure firewall for my dc?

Greetings

Comment: No need to open port on firewall as long as they are in the same VNet.  When you update the VNet DNS did you reboot the client VM? Once the VM is rebooted you should use IPConfig to confirm DNS is confirmed on client VM to use DC's IP.

Comment: There was another problem. It's running now. Thanks for the hint.